# How to render a list by date while grouping the items with the same date in a div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of 100+ objects with a date value in each obj:

```
let items = [
  {
    ...,
    date: '1/25/2020
  }, {
    ...,
    date: '1/25/2020
  }, {
    ...,
    date: 1/24/2020
  }, {
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

My problem right now is that I am trying to build out all of these items grouped by date.

This is some incorrect code that I have:

```
let currentDate = ''

<div className={`items-container ${isLoading ? 'is-loading' : undefined}`}>
    {
        !isLoading &&
        items.map((item, i) => {
            if (new Date(item.created_at).toLocaleDateString() === currentDate) {
                return (
                    <div>
                        <p>{item.message}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            } else {
                return (
                    <>
                        <div className='date-group'>
                            etc etc
                        </div>
                    </>
                )
            }
        })
    }
</div>
```

The end result would look something like this where items with the same date are within the same date-group div

```
<div className='date-group'>
  <div className='item'></div>
  <div className='item'></div>
  <div className='item'></div>
</div>
<div className='date-group'>
  <div className='item'></div>
  <div className='item'></div>
</div>
<div className='date-group'>
  <div className='item'></div>
  <div className='item'></div>
  <div className='item'></div>
</div>
```

Useful note, the array is already sorted by the date so there is no need to sort first.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simplified example of what you're going for. First, we group the `items` array by date in an object, and then we use `Object.entries` to iterate through those groupings.

```
let items = [{
    message: "First",
    date: "1/25/2020"
  }, {
    message: "Second",
    date: "1/25/2020"
  }, {
    message: "Third",
    date: "1/24/2020"
  }];

// Group your items
grouped = items.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if(!acc[el.date]) acc[el.date] = [];
  acc[el.date].push(el);
  return acc;
}, {});
```

In your JSX, you can now map through your entries

```
{Object.entries(grouped).map(([date, options]) => {
  return (
  <div className='date-group'>
    {options.map(el => <div className='item'>{el.message}</div>)}
  </div>
  )
})}
```